# Which is better for MSSQL hosted on Azure, a bigger cost of CPU or RAM?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I had a not-well performing query, so i rewrote it by using many tricks, `cte`s, removing unused columns, `select *` around, and so on..

In the end, I have 2 views, the old one has a bigger cost on CPU but less in memory and lasts a bit more time. The 2nd has a lower cost on CPU, ends faster, but has a bigger cost in RAM.

Which one should be the best? Considering that Azure is hosting the DB, which one will cost more in an economical point of view?

Comment: cost wise I found postgresql to be cheaper when using the azure managed postgres offering. though the database usage was quite normal and nothing too performance intensive